# Dojo DataGrid (8.5.3 UP1) Returning Blank Rows - based on Readers field

Tags: xpages, dojox.grid.datagrid, xpages-extlib

Trying out a Dojo DataGrid control on an alternate XPage (so as not to impact production) for an existing View, which utilizes Readers fields in the documents. I've got the REST service implemented (xe:viewItemFileService) and connected to the Dojo DataGrid just fine (from 8.5.3 UP1 controls).

I have two scenarios of user visibility (via Roles in the Readers field, assigned by NAB Group definition):

1. All documents visible (user A). User A can see all documents, everything works perfectly fine for this one.
2. User B can see some documents. ViewPanel control works fine, but once it's in the Dojo DataGrid, it only has values for the documents User B should see, the remaining X (difference between correctly visible and total document count) rows are populated with "..." (non-values).

Inspecting the REST service's output via the pathInfo yields only the correct documents for User B; which I take as a good sign and makes me think the Dojo DataGrid is what's misbehaving.

**Actual Question**:
How can I suppress the generation of the unnecessary rows?

I've tried to implement [Marky Roden's approach](http://xomino.com/2013/03/12/searching-xpages-rest-service-and-returning-the-real-count-in-the-results/), but got lost on the manipulation of how I can control what the DataGrid is looking at to generate row count (he's talking programmatic store definitions when I'm using the xe:djxDataGrid control). The  attribute of rowsPerPage doesn't seem right, and I can't find one for the xe:restService that would make sense to me for what I'm looking for.

Anyone know how to do this? Would love to get this work. Been loving the series by [Brad Balassaitis](http://xcellerant.net/2013/05/01/dojo-data-grid-part-14-enhanced-filtering-with-no-coding/) and what XPages can do for us.

Setup:
Domino Server 8.5.3 UP1
NSF signed as Server ID

Comment: I should note that everything is as expected in the primary (for now) XPage, which utilizes a stock xp:viewPanel control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid gets the hint for the number of rows from ?readViewEntriews which tells the actual number, not just the number of documents user B can see. Anyway just romping through reader protected views without designing for access speed has [huge performance ramifications](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-7PNDF7). If you can categorize the view by the combined reader/author fields and limit to that category both performance and empty rows will go away.
If you have multiple possible hits (username, role, group membership), you might want to use a rest service that returns data using some SSJS using a viewNavigator

Comment: Thank you. I can't help but think categorizing by role will be a nightmare (lots of roles for a very distributed permissions setup), but I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: Running uncategorized is a performance nightmare. And why do you think it would be a nightmare? it is just one column where you have the field(s) that contain the reader and author entries. It doesn't matter if you have one or 50 roles. The interesting part is more: how many roles will any given user have

Comment: Performance is effort. Either effort for the CPU or your brain. Brain is once, CPU on every page view.

Comment: It varies greatly based on the user. I'm all for planning up front for better performance, was just hoping my Readers fields would be more magical. Not expecting an actual nightmare.

Comment: The magic is here: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-7PNDF7 - no nightmare involved. Once you wrap your head around it, it is actually obvious. Even in your standard view control you have the performance issue - you might not know it. Typical problem: we test with small data sets or with a user who can see most documents -> performance is OK. Once you use large data but a user who can see few only the performance trouble starts

Comment: Thanks for the link on the topic. Glad to know this isn't a new thing. On the down side, I believe that with a category filter on a View based xe:restService control, I lose the ability to sort. Brad Balassaitis talks about this at the end of his article (in the series) on FT search and [filtering](http://xcellerant.net/2013/04/18/dojo-data-grid-10-searching-and-filtering/).