# viewJsonService returning too many entries to dataGrid

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I've set up an ExtLib REST service as "xe:viewJsonService" and connected it to a domino view. Currently the view contains 63 entries. The documents behind those entries have read access restrictions.

The Json returned by the service is consumed by a Dojo Data Grid (taken from the ExtLib libraries).

The page is accessed by a test user having read access to only one of the 64 entries. This user however sees a data grid containing a single data element, followed by 63 empty entries, like this:

[image]

Looking at the raw Json data I see that the service indeed is only returning a single entry, but it knows that there are 63 siblings:

```
[
  {
      "@entryid":"1-6C5763E4A122F1D3C1257EC700355386",
      "@unid":"6C5763E4A122F1D3C1257EC700355386",
      "@noteid":"3FD2E",
      "@position":"1",
      "@read":true,
      "@siblings":63,
      "@form":"fInvoice",
      "colIconStatus":"imgInvExported.gif",
      "colIconLock":"blank.gif",
      "invInvoiceDate":"2015-09-21T09:44:27Z",
      "invJobInvNumbers":"111\/5152\/52567\/ 001",
      "invSupplierNameShort":"My Test Company GmbH",
      "invAmount":121.5
  }
]
```

Technically speaking this is correct as the service has access to all 64 entries. Problem is that the data grid is making space for 64 entries instead of only one.

Question is: how can I tell the data grid the correct amount of data to be displayed? Or do I need to manipulate the REST service instead?

EDIT: continuing my search for a possible solution in meanwhile found a few other related questions [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339613/dojo-datagrid-8-5-3-up1-returning-blank-rows-based-on-readers-field) by Eric McCormick (including a very good approach by Stephan Wissel), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798495/hide-blank-rows-in-dojo-data-grid) by Steve Zavocki. So my question would be a duplicate, really... (sorry for that)

Answer (score 2):

**Caveat:** please read down to the bottom of this answer as you might run into unexpected ussues!

Finally after some playing around I just stumbled upon an obscure property that seems to help, for whatever reason (I'll be making this a new question):
the property `globalValues` appears to be available for service types `xe:documentJsonService`, `xe:viewItemFileService`, `xe:viewJsonLegacyService`, `xe:viewJsonService` and `xe:viewXmlLegacyService`. this property has three fixed options called `Entries` (= 0x0001), `Top Level` (= 0x0002) and `Timestamp` (= 0x0004). Just by playing the goold old "trial-and-error" game I found that setting this property to 1 (= Entries) modifies / filters the resulting data:

by default the raw JSON returned by `xe:viewItemFileService` looks like this:

```
{
    "@timestamp":"2015-10-14T12:57:59Z",
    "@toplevelentries":63,
    "items":
    [
      {
          ...
      }
    ]
}
```

Setting `globalValues` to "1" removes the `@timestamp` and `@toplevelentries` fields from the output:

```
{
    "items":
    [
      {
          ...
      }
    ]
}
```

And, more importantly, this also removes the empty rows from my data grid!

There's only one thing that's making me nervous and that is that I can't find any explanation at all in regards to that property. So I really don't have a clue whether there are any unwanted side effects...

**Update:** thanks to Knut Herrmann I did some more testing on this (see comments below this answer). In my test case there are over 13,000 documents in my view; as long as my test user can only read a small amount of those everything seems to be fine. Then I added 200 more documents to the read-enabled list. Result is a data-grid that constantly has to recalculate its scroll bar: the further down I'm scrolling the smaller the scroll handle gets. As soon as I reach the bottom line however the grid goes berzerk and decides to only display the first 13 (?!?) rows, and also the scroll bar is removed alltogether. Performance isn't as bad as I expected, though.

So I have to agree with Knut that this isn't such a good solution for the combination of large views with a large subset of accessible entries!

Comment: How does the data grid act if you have a view with e.g. 1000 entries? Does the vertical slider still work? This could be difficult to handle for data grid as it doesn't get the information anymore how many entries are there in total and on what position is the current REST chunk...

Comment: to be honest I don't know; this particular view won't have much more than 100 entries. At the time being it contains 63 entries, and - being set to show 25 entries at once - a vertical scroll bar is showing. With other views however I had the same issues before I decided to switch to single categories, and those views contain over 10,000 entries. Scroll bar was working on those although I can't tell whether there were indeed 10,000 empty rows... - good idea to try that option on a real big view

Comment: @Knut: just gave it a try with a non-categorized view containing 13,100 entries of which my test user can access 7. Without globalValues = "1" the data grid shows thiose 7 docs plus a huge number of empty rows; scroll bar works fine as I can scroll down to the very end and back up again (no, I didn't count the emptyness...). Then set globalValues to 1, re-built the page source. Result is showing my 7 accessible entries and nothing else. Performance seems to be OK, although there aren't any concurrent users on that server right now. - next I'll try read-enabling more documents for my user

Comment: Thanks for tests. I think performance will be the same or even better with option globalValues = "1" as REST service don't have to add some global attributes and don't have to count entries. Possible scroll bar issue will only appear if user can read a lot of documents like 1000...

Comment: Follow-up on my last comment: you're right, data grid obviously is losing track at some point: now with more than 200 out of 13,000 docs being read-enabled data grid constantly needs to re-calculate the scroll bar's size and position, and if I scroll down to the very bottom of it it gets lost alltogether, i.e. it simply disappears. So that option is no real use, I'm afraid (I'll edit my answer above - thanks for makting me go into greater detail!)

Answer (score 1):

Lothar,

I have experienced this before as you pointed out.  I believe the answer is to use the 'keys' property to filter out the invalid entries.

I am not sure about how your application is structured, but if the user can only see certain entries in the view, I would consider categorizing by user, and then use the keys to show them only the rows in which they have access.

You asked if you can change the dojo grid to exclude the entries. I think the answer there is no. Your options are to filter via the REST service or via the Notes view.

Here is a related blog post that I wrote on the issues I was having. http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/07/creating-updatable-rest-service-for-use.html

---

**EDIT**   ***2 Additional Things to Try***

1) Did you see the comment on my blog post? I haven't tried it myself. Credit goes to blog comment-er "Goo Goo".

"I use this code in `onstyleRow` event of the grid to solve the blank rows issue "

*which using viewJsonService:*

```
var row = arguments[0];
var rowItem = djxDataGrid1.getItem(row.index);
var rowCount = Object.keys(restService1._index).length - 1; //-1 for omit the onUpdate event
if(row.index >= rowCount){
row.customStyles += 'display:none;';
}
```

2) What I personally did to fix the issue is in this SO answer: [How to configure an xe:viewFileItemService on an XPage to filter the data in a categorized view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153238/how-to-configure-an-xeviewfileitemservice-on-an-xpage-to-filter-the-data-in-a-c/29182174#29182174)

Given what you said about your view structure, I am not sure that this will apply to you.

Comment: In fact I tried "keys" as in "getAllEntriesByKey", but the result was the same. What does help is the single category approach which I'm using in 99% of my views, but not in this one. I just was about to alter that view when I stimbled upon some obscure property (see my own answer, which unfortunatelxy leads to another question...)

Comment: I edited my answer with 2 addl things to try.  Good luck